# Windows Powershell: Set-Clipboard after Select-String gives error "Cannot find path 'C:\MyDirectory\InputStream' because it does not exist"

Tags: powershell, windows-10, clipboard

I want to pipe the output of a Select-String command to the clipboard. I have tried piping to `clip.exe` with `<command_with_long_output> <args> | select-string <string_of_interest> | clip`, but this copies the line ending so that when I paste it tries to execute.

If I use something like `echo hello | set-clipboard`, it does not copy the new line, so I can paste without it trying to execute.

But if I try to combine `set-clipboard` and `select-string`, I get an error:

```
PS C:\Users\chickman> echo "hello" | select-string hello | set-clipboard
set-clipboard : Cannot find path 'C:\Users\chickman\InputStream' because it does not exist.
At line:1 char:38
+ echo "hello" | select-string hello | set-clipboard
+                                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Clipboard:String) [Set-Clipboard], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FailedToSetClipboard,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetClipboardCommand
```

Why does this happen and how can I get around it?

*Edit:

I have just tried

```
echo "hello" | select-string hello | out-string | set-clipboard
```

And this no longer gives the error, but I am now back to square one as this adds a new line, so when I try to paste it tries to execute the command!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested it on PS 5.1.
According to the doc, `select-string` is returning matching lines  from input lines: this gave no suprise for the trailing newline. However, when I ran
`echo "hello" | select-string hello`
I got a
*`[newline]`*
`hello`
*`[newline]`*
*`[newline]`*
so I did a
`echo "hello" | select-string hello | .{process {$_.GetType()}}`
which showed, that the result is not `string` but a `MatchInfo` object, so with an explicit cast I succeeded with
`echo "hello" | select-string hello | .{process {[string]$_}} | Set-Clipboard`

Comment: Instead of a scriptblock, you could use `ForEach-Object` or it's alias `%`: `echo "hello" | select-string hello | % { [string]$_ } | Set-Clipboard`

Comment: @Vivere Indeed, possibly there are multiple ways to avoid scriptblocks, I just like to show people how to use them, as it should be known.

Comment: Thanks! I thought that `select-string` might have been returning something other than a string. The `.{process {[string]$_}}` is a bit cumbersome though. I was trying to duplicate my linux workflow, and not have to switch between keyboard and mouse. But at this point it will just be quicker to highlight the line from the `select-string` and press ctrl-c.